# WebFlux.fn doesn't route at all

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use WebFlux.fn.

I wrote a Web controller and it works.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/employees")
public class EmployeesController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/{id:.+}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> read(
            @PathVariable(name = "id) String id) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(method = PUT, path = "/{id:.+}", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void updated(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id,
                        @RequestBody Employee entity) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(method = DELETE, path = "/{id:.+}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    }
}
```

And I also wrote a Reactive Web controller and it also works.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/employees/reactive")
public class EmployeesReactiveController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/{id:.+"}, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Employee> read(
            @PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(method = PUT, path = "/{id:.+}", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Boolean> updated(
            @PathVariable(name = PATH_NAME_EMPLOYEE_ID) String id,
            @RequestBody Employee entity) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(method = DELETE, path = "/{id:.+}")
    public Mono<Long> delete(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    }
}
```

And I'm stuck with an WebFlux.fn version.

```java
@Configuration
public class EmployeesReactiveFnConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> employeesRouterFunction(
            EmployeesReactiveFnHandler handler) {
        return route(GET("/api/v1/employees/reactive/fn/{id:.+}"), handler::read);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class EmployeesReactiveFnHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> read(@NotBlank String id) {
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> read(ServerRequest request) {
        return read(request.pathVariable("id"));
    }
}
```

These two classes seem to be recognized by Spring.

```
...DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'employeesReactiveFnConfig'
...DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'employeesReactiveFnHandler'
```

Whenever I tried I got this.

```
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/api/v1/employees/reactive/fn/......' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/v1/employees/reactive/fn/...... has an empty filter list
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/api/v1/employees/reactive/fn/......", parameters={}
o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/error' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error has an empty filter list
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [{timestamp=Fri Mar 20 18:54:24 KST 2020, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

My current dependency tree looks like this. (Some removed for brevity)

```
>mvn dependency:tree | grep springframework
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.3.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
```

Comment: can you please show what the request you are making looks like

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I'm just calling these endpoints via Postman.

Comment: i didn't ask what program you were using, i asked to see what your request looks like. Since you are getting a 404 you are doing a request to an endpoint that the server doesn't recognise and i'd like to eliminate human error before pursuing anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is not a WebFlux application - the HATEOAS dependency is bringing Spring MVC transitively.

You can remove this dependency if it's not used (Spring HATOAS also supports WebFlux in recent version, but [the auto-configuration is not complete yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16020)). You can also [force the type of web application in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-web-app-type), with the `spring.main.web-application-type` configuration property.